# rounding up time in python error

Tags: python, datetime

I get the following error when trying to round up time,

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

fajr_jamaat1 printout is  1900-01-01 04:25:00
Please help?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def round_up(tm):
    upmins = math.ceil(float(tm.minute)/10)*10
    diffmins = upmins - tm.minute
    newtime = tm + datetime.timedelta(minutes=diffmins)
    newtime = newtime.replace(second=0)
    return newtime

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_remote_host, user=mysql_remote_host_user, password=mysql_remote_host_password, database=mysql_remote_host_database)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from paramatta_prayertimes WHERE id =1")
results = cursor.fetchall()
id, date, fajr_begins, fajr_jamaat, sunrise, zuhr_begins, zuhr_jamaat, asr_begins, asr_jamaat, maghrib_jamaat, isha_begins, isha_jamaat = results[0]
cursor.close()
print fajr_begins

fajr_jamaat1=(timedelta(minutes=20) + datetime.strptime(str(fajr_begins), "%H:%M:%S"))
print fajr_jamaat1
round_up(fajr_jamaat1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you imported your functions as

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

You do not need to call the function as

```
datetime.timedelta
```

You simply call the function by its name

```
timedelta
```

If you prefer to use the former syntax, just import the module itself

```
import datetime
```

Then you can say

```
datetime.datetime
datetime.timedelta
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 newtime = tm + datetime.timedelta(minutes=diffmins)
```

=>

```
 newtime = tm + timedelta(minutes=diffmins)
```